# What is the best method to Convert rtmp stream to udp, using nginx and ffmpeg?

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, udp, rtmp, cisco

I am getting a rtmp stream with an NginX server, and i would like to send it to Cisco DCM, that is waiting for udp stream.
I tried to use ffmpeg inside my NginX server, but the stream does not seems to carry anything...

Here is my NginX/rtmp module config:

```
rtmp {
server {
        listen 1935;
        chunk_size 4096;

        application live {
                live on;
                record off;
                allow publish 127.0.0.1;
                allow publish @ip_stream_souce;
                deny publish all;

                #Captation flux
                exec_static ffmpeg -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/stream_name -c copy -f mpegts udp://239.0.0.12:1234;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved try the below commands

```
        exec ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost:1935/live/stream-name -codec copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:2555;
```